# Rearranging a table converting values to column names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As a result of an XML implementation on achieving a dynamic data entry tool, I was left with the below table

```
TRGID   C_NAME     I_ID COLUMNID    TARGET_DESC     DEPT_NAME   VALUE

20158   Outlook     2   1000        Production      Operations  2.501
20158   Outlook     4   1000        Production      Operations  1.5
20158   Outlook     3   1000        Production      Operations  0.2
20158   Outlook     1   1000        Production      Operations  1.9
20158   Target      1   2111        Production      Operations  2.1
20158   Target      4   2111        Production      Operations  1.2
20158   Target      2   2111        Production      Operations  11.2
20158   Target      3   2111        Production      Operations  1.58
20158   Month       4   3222        Production      Operations  1-May-2010
20158   Month       3   3222        Production      Operations  1-Apr-2010
20158   Month       2   3222        Production      Operations  1-Jan-2015
20158   Month       1   3222        Production      Operations  1-Mar-2015
20158   Actual      4   4333        Production      Operations  2.5
20158   Actual      3   4333        Production      Operations  3.5
20158   Actual      2   4333        Production      Operations  10.8
20158   Actual      1   4333        Production      Operations  2
20163   Month       2   1000        Maintenance     Operations  1-Feb-2015
20163   Month       1   1000        Maintenance     Operations  1-Jan-2010
20163   Outlook     2   2111        Maintenance     Operations  18.56
20163   Outlook     1   2111        Maintenance     Operations  2.3
20163   Actual      2   3222        Maintenance     Operations  28.2
20163   Actual      1   3222        Maintenance     Operations  1.4
20163   Goal        2   4333        Maintenance     Operations  3.98
20163   Goal        1   4333        Maintenance     Operations  3.6
```

I would like the result to be as follows

```
TRGID   I_ID      Month      Actual  Outlook    Target      Goal
20158    1      1-Mar-2015     2       1.9        2.1   
20158    2      1-Jan-2015     10.8    2.501      11.2  
20158    3      1-Apr-2010     3.5     0.2        1.58  
20158    4      1-May-2010     2.5     1.5        1.2   
20163    1      1-Jan-2010     1.4     2.3                  3.6
20163    2      1-Feb-2015     28.2    18.56                3.98
```

I would like a solution which would adapt to changes in the data and not the current data only.

I am using Oracle 10g

Comment: This is too vague a question to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: How is it vague, if you did not understand something ask. Being critical on it adds no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pivot if you have Oracle 11g

```
WITH table_(TRGID, C_NAME, I_ID, COLUMNID, TARGET_DESC, DEPT_NAME, VALUE) AS 
(
    select 20158, 'Outlook', 2, 1000, 'Production', 'Operations', '2.501' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Outlook', 4, 1000, 'Production', 'Operations', '1.5' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Outlook', 3, 1000, 'Production', 'Operations', '0.2' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Outlook', 1, 1000, 'Production', 'Operations', '1.9' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Target', 1, 2111, 'Production', 'Operations', '2.1' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Target', 4, 2111, 'Production', 'Operations', '1.2' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Target', 2, 2111, 'Production', 'Operations', '11.2' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Target', 3, 2111, 'Production', 'Operations', '1.58' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Month', 4, 3222, 'Production', 'Operations', '1-May-2010' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Month', 3, 3222, 'Production', 'Operations', '1-Apr-2010' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Month', 2, 3222, 'Production', 'Operations', '1-Jan-2015' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Month', 1, 3222, 'Production', 'Operations', '1-Mar-2015' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Actual', 4, 4333, 'Production', 'Operations', '2.5' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Actual', 3, 4333, 'Production', 'Operations', '3.5' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Actual', 2, 4333, 'Production', 'Operations', '10.8' from dual union all
    select 20158, 'Actual', 1, 4333, 'Production', 'Operations', '2' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Month', 2, 1000, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '1-Feb-2015' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Month', 1, 1000, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '1-Jan-2010' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Outlook', 2, 2111, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '18.56' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Outlook', 1, 2111, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '2.3' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Actual', 2, 3222, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '28.2' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Actual', 1, 3222, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '1.4' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Goal', 2, 4333, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '3.98' from dual union all
    select 20163, 'Goal', 1, 4333, 'Maintenance', 'Operations', '3.6' from dual)
-- End if data Preparation
    SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT trgid,
                   c_name,
                   i_id,
                   VALUE
              FROM table_) pivot(MIN(VALUE) FOR c_name IN('Month' AS MONTH,
                                                          'Actual' AS actual,
                                                          'Outlook' as outlook,
                                                          'Target' AS target,
                                                          'Goal' AS goal))
```

Output

```
| TRGID | I_ID |      MONTH | ACTUAL | OUTLOOK | TARGET |   GOAL |
|-------|------|------------|--------|---------|--------|--------|
| 20158 |    2 | 1-Jan-2015 |   10.8 |   2.501 |   11.2 | (null) |
| 20163 |    1 | 1-Jan-2010 |    1.4 |     2.3 | (null) |    3.6 |
| 20163 |    2 | 1-Feb-2015 |   28.2 |   18.56 | (null) |   3.98 |
| 20158 |    1 | 1-Mar-2015 |      2 |     1.9 |    2.1 | (null) |
| 20158 |    4 | 1-May-2010 |    2.5 |     1.5 |    1.2 | (null) |
| 20158 |    3 | 1-Apr-2010 |    3.5 |     0.2 |   1.58 | (null) |
```

For versions < 11 g, use below query,

```
SELECT trgid,
       i_id,
       MIN(CASE c_name WHEN 'Month' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS MONTH,
       MIN(CASE c_name WHEN 'Actual' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS actual,
       MIN(CASE c_name WHEN 'Outlook' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS outlook,
       MIN(CASE c_name WHEN 'Target' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS target,
       MIN(CASE c_name WHEN 'Goal' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) AS goal
  FROM table_
 GROUP BY trgid, i_id;
```

Comment: Hi San, I get unsupported column aliasing "column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet"

Comment: Hi @San I managed to solve the column aliasing by replacing WITH table_(TRGID, C_NAME, I_ID, COLUMNID, TARGET_DESC, DEPT_NAME, VALUE) AS with WITH TABLE_ AS however I have an error running the query "SQL command not properly ended at PIVOT

Comment: Since I am using Oracle 10g I use CASE instead of PIVOT